# spring cloud stream kafka CommitFailedException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I used spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka 3.0.4.RELEASE, i have the below error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:900)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:840)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:978)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:958)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:578)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:388)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:294)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:303)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1104)
```

Configuration:

```
spring:
   cloud: 
     stream:  
       bindings:
         default:
           content-type: application/*+avro
         inputAddAccount:
           destination: dev_account
           group: dev_group
         ouputUpdateFile:
           destination: dev_update_file
           group: dev_group
           producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
       kafka:
         binder:
           brokers: kafka1-dev:6667
           auto-create-topics: false
           consumer-properties:
             auto.offset.reset: latest
             auto.commit.interval.ms: 1000
             specific.avro.reader: true
             key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
             value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
             schema.registry.url: https://schema-registry1.dev:8088
             basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
             basic.auth.user.info: reader:reader
           producer-properties:
             acks: -1
             retries: 2147483647
             max.in.flight.requests.per.connection : 1
             request.timeout.ms: 10000
             key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
             value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
             schema.registry.url: https://schema-registry1.dev:8088
             basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
             basic.auth.user.info: reader:reader
```

Answer (score 1):

**org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.**

They above exception occurs when your consumer takes longer time to process a message than session.timeout.ms or max.poll.interval.ms. Also, looking at your configuration, I am not seeing these properties, that means your consumer is using default values. Kindly check those values and if it is less than the avg time of processing a record, kindly overwrite them with a longer values.